# How to Date Tag from xml as DateTime datatype into the application

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I have written XML file having a Date `<Date>10/11/2011</Date>` tag in it as above and trying to read it from VB.NET:

```
If TypeOf item Is DateTime Then
    nextItem = DirectCast(item, DateTime).ToString("MMM-d-yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff", ci)
End If
```

How to get the date tag in XML in datetime format in the application? (As I am getting the date  value as string in the application)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `XmlConvert.ToDateTime()` will do the trick...

(See [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/35xk5aza.aspx))